# Failed to add user: [cloud_firestore/unknown] Expected a value of type '((Object) => Object)?', but got one of type '(Object?) => dynamic

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to user firestore on flutter null safety version but I have this problem when getting data or write data

> Failed to add user: [cloud_firestore/unknown] Expected a value of type '((Object) => Object)?', but got one of type '(Object?) => dynamic'

this is sample widget I tried

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Import the firebase_core and cloud_firestore plugin
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class AddUser extends StatelessWidget {
  final String fullName;
  final String company;
  final int age;

AddUser(this.fullName, this.company, this.age);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// Create a CollectionReference called users that references the firestore collection
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<void> addUser() {
  // Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new user
  return users
      .add({
        'full_name': fullName, // John Doe
        'company': company, // Stokes and Sons
        'age': age // 42
      })
      .then((value) => print("User Added"))
      .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
}

return TextButton(
  onPressed: addUser,
  child: Text(
    "Add User",
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: I do not see something wrong in the code, could you please print the values before trying to save? Maybe the values are causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded to Flutter 2 and the nullsafety version of dart, but the project seems to be twisted in the process, so I changed it to a new project base and it worked.

Comment: I'm very happy you issue is no longer present, will you mind if I make a community wiki response?